# moment convert this DD.MM.YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have an API that accepts a date in this format **20.02.2020**, but I have to save it in MySql, so I need this format **2020/02/20**, I have tried using replace function and regex. But didn't get the desired output.

```
let dt='20.02.2020';
dt.replace('/./g','')
```

Comment: dt.replace(/\./g, '/')

Comment: try using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235315/11046080

Comment: `dt.split(".").reverse().join("/")` should work

Comment: new Date('20.02.2020'.split('.').reverse()).toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/\-/g, '/')

Answer (score 1):

Import moment through npm and pass desired dataFormat as argument.

```
  moment(date, moment.ISO_8601, true).local().format(dateFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of many regex solutions:

```
dt.replace(/([0-9]*?)\.([0-9]*?)\.([0-9]*)/gmi, '$3\/$2\/$1');
```

I find the most elegant solution if you have to reuse dt's value is the split reverse and join which was demonstrated by [Tewathia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003352/tewathia)